# Check IPA suppprted devices

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, compatibility, ipa

How can we check what devices are supported by my IPA?
I have created my IPA using `cordova`, I did settings in `build.xcconfig` file to work my IPA only for **iPhone** devices as follows

```
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1
```

I also done settings in `PROJECT_NAME-info.plist` file as

`<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<dict>
    <key>bluetooth-le</key>
</dict>`

[image: Application Install Screen]
In Compatibility section of above image, there is big list of devices supported and it includes iPad mini, iPad.... and many more...
I wish to see text "iPhone 8.0 or later" only which says application supports only iPhone device... How can I achieve this?

I am not sure but is my `blutooth-le` setting which causing so many devices in compatibility section?

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you make this setting in Xcode?

Comment: @Joerg.. I am actually using a build script to make IPA. I am using `cordova build ios --device --release` command to create IPA, so I want to set this things using config files. Can I check supported devices of IPA?

Comment: Then you should try this plugin: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config

Comment: Oh.. ok thanks @Joerg.. Let me try this one..!!